# How to define dependency version only once for whole Gradle multi-module project?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, gradle-plugin

I made a decision to migrate from [Dependency Management Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/) to [Gradle built-in BOM import support](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html). Since **Gradle built-in BOM import support** [has better performance](https://youtu.be/AADeX1AEmzU?t=1719) But

**I run into the issue:**

I cannot find alternatives for [dependency](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/#dependency-management-configuration-dsl) and [dependencySet](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/#dependency-management-configuration-dsl) in native Gradle:

```
    dependencyManagement {
        dependencies {
            dependency("org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.3.RELEASE")
        }
    }
//or
    dependencyManagement {
         dependencies {
              dependencySet(group:'org.slf4j', version: '1.7.7') {
                   entry 'slf4j-api'
                   entry 'slf4j-simple'
              }
         }
    }
```

and then I could use dependency without version

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core'
}
```

How can I get **the same behavior in naive Gradle**?  I mean: I'd like to define a version **once** as I did it when using [Dependency Management Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/)

Answer (score 2):

Solution below helps to avoid versions copy-paste. However it isn't the same with Dependency Management plugin.

**For Gradle Kotlin Dsl:**

You can create `buildSrc` with you own code, when you can place any constants.

Algorithm:

1. Create folder `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin`
2. Create file `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Versions.kt` with content:

```
object Versions {
    const val junitVersion = "5.5.5" // just example
}
```

3. Create file `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` with content:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
```

4. Use the following syntax in your gradle.kts files:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:${Versions.junitVersion}")
}
```

**For Gradle Groovy:**

1. Create file `gradle.properties`
2. Put versions there with syntax like `okhttp_version=4.2.0`
3. Use the following syntax in your gradle files:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: okhttp_version
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so on the `gradle.properties` file. I.e.:

```
# APPLICATION PROPERTIES
name=projectName
group=com.domain
version=1.0.0
description=A brief description

gradleScripts=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hexagonkt/hexagon/1.2.0/gradle

# DEPENDENCIES VERSIONS
kotlinVersion=1.3.61
kotlinCoroutinesVersion=1.3.2
```

Or in `settings.gradle` if you don't want to create another file:

```
rootProject.name = "hexagon-contact-application"

gradle.rootProject {

    allprojects {
        version = "1.0.0"
        group = "org.hexagonkt"
        description = "Contact application backend api"
    }

    extensions.gradleScripts = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hexagonkt/hexagon/1.0.18/gradle"

    extensions.kotlinVersion = "1.3.50"
    extensions.kotlinCoroutinesVersion = "1.3.2"

    extensions.hexagonVersion = "1.0.21"

    extensions.logbackVersion = "1.2.3"
    extensions.bcryptVersion="0.8.0"
    extensions.javaJwtVersion="3.8.2"
}
```

And if you want to avoid adding the version variable to all related dependencies, you can create a method in the build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.50'
}

apply from: "$gradleScripts/kotlin.gradle"
apply from: "$gradleScripts/service.gradle"
apply from: "$gradleScripts/junit.gradle"

defaultTasks("test")

mainClassName = 'com.hexagonkt.contact.ApplicationKt'
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Xms64M", "-Xmx2G", "-XX:+UseNUMA", "-XX:+UseParallelGC"]

dependencies {
    httpkt(it, "http_server_jetty")
    httpkt(it, "store_mongodb")
    httpkt(it, "hexagon_web")

    implementation("at.favre.lib:bcrypt:$bcryptVersion")
    implementation("com.auth0:java-jwt:$javaJwtVersion")

    testImplementation("com.hexagonkt:port_http_client:$hexagonVersion")
}

private void httpkt(final def dependencies, final String artifact) {
    dependencies.implementation("com.hexagonkt:$artifact:$hexagonVersion")
}
```